# javascript compare Two Times

Tags: javascript

Trying to get it to change between 16:30:00 and 17:30:00, to change the text font colour

Tried nested if statements as well

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
 
 if ((h>=16 && m >=30) && (h<=17 && m<=30))
 {
     document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "red"; 
 }
 else
 {
document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "black"; 
 }
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;

}
```

Comment: Add your problem is? What's your code doing? Does it give errors? How does it behave and how does that differ from what you were trying to do?

Comment: Also `((h>=16 && m >=30) && (h<=17 && m<=30))` m can't be `< 30` && `>30`, so this will only evaluate to true when `m == 30`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MattBurland good point, it seems the problem. Should be OR logical operator

Comment: Click the "Run code snippet" button in your question. Notice how the results are blank? That's because you haven't included the HTML on which this code runs, nor added the code which calls `startTime()`.

Comment: I bet it would work at exactly 16:30 and 17:30! (hint: I'd convert the hour/minute to one number like `(h * 60) + m`, then use that to simplify your comparisons)

Comment: well you also turn `m` and `s` into strings for values < 10

Comment: @ChrisForrence never, at least in relative time of planet Earth, you can stay on 16:30 and 17:30 at the same time.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That wasn't what I meant ;) It would show red at 16:30, show black from 16:31 to 17:29, then show red at 17:30.

Answer (score 2):

try to use setInterval() it's look more clear:

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();

    if((h==16 && m>=30) || (h==17 && m<=30)){
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "red"; 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "black";   
    }
};

setInterval(startTime, 500);
```

Comment: Good idea using setInterval instead of setTimeout! Just a small suggestion; I'd also say that you changed the logic in the if-statement from AND to OR.

Answer (score 1):

The main bug in your logic is looking for minutes where it is both less than and equal to 30 AND greater than and equal to 30. The only way that part evaluates to true is if minutes is 30.

I would normalize the time (so that each combination of hour, minute and second can be represented by a unique number) and use that for comparisons.

```js
function startTime(el) {
  var today = new Date();
  var hour = today.getHours(),
    minute = today.getMinutes(),
    second = today.getSeconds();
  var normalized_time = normalizeTime(hour, minute, second);

  document.getElementById(el).innerHTML 
    = hour + ":" + padTime(minute) + ":" + padTime(second);

  document.getElementById(el).style.color 
    = normalized_time >= normalizeTime(16, 30, 0) 
      && normalized_time <= normalizeTime(17, 30, 0)
    ? 'red'
    : 'black';
}

/*
 * Add a 0 to the beginning of the number if one-digit number
 */
function padTime(i) {
  return i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
}

/*
 * Converts the time to a normalized version
 */
function normalizeTime(h, m, s) {
  return s + (60 * m) + (60 * 60 * h);
}

var t = setInterval(startTime, 500, 'txt');
```

```html
<span id="txt"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As per you question you want to take hour and minute into account for comparison, So i have not included the second's part.

The following function get an integer value against time , that later used for the comparison.

```
function getSeconds(hh,mm,ss)
{
    return (Number(hh) * 60 * 60) + (Number(mm) * 60) + Number(ss);
}
```

Complete code :

```
function getSeconds(hh,mm,ss)
{
    return (Number(hh) * 60 * 60) + (Number(mm) * 60) + Number(ss);
}
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
      var timeNow = getSeconds(h,m,s);
    //if ((h>=16 && m >=30) && (h<=17 && m<=30))
  if (timeNow >= getSeconds(16,30,0) && timeNow <= getSeconds(17,30,00))
    {
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "red"; 
    }
    else
    {
document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "black";   
    }
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;

}
startTime();
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a9ef411/3/)

---

**Previous Response**

Try the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a9ef411/1/)

The problem with your code is you are comparing `m` with contradictory conditions.

I have concatenated the hour and minutes like following and used that for time comparison

`var hrs = Number(h+'.'+m);`

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    var hrs = Number(h+'.'+m);
    //if ((h>=16 && m >=30) && (h<=17 && m<=30))
    if (hrs >= 16.30 && hrs <= 17.30)
    {
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "red"; 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "black";   
    }
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;

}
startTime();
```

Comment: So it basically converts the time into a string and comparing a string?

Comment: Not quite; it converts the time into a decimal number (the hour is the integer-part, the minute is the fractional-part) and compares based on that.

Comment: oh ok, so basically converts the time into a float and compares that number. IS there a way of adding another .00 to it for seconds?